# How to remove the black space between the title bar and the first element of a LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I have a linearlayout, which the first element is a imageview header, and the second element is a gridview.

It works fine, but I have a erroneal black space of 50px (more or less) between the android title bar and the header of the app, which is the first element of the linearlayout

Why do I have that space? The only way I find to remove it is to put this line:  `ll.setPadding(0, -50, 0, 0);`

This is the full code:

```
public class MainGrid extends Activity {
    private GridView myGridView;
    private ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
    private ImageView header;
    
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);//turn off the window's title bar
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);//fullscreen
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    //ll.setPadding(0, -50, 0, 0);
    header = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    header.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_acc);
    
    myGridView = new GridView(this);
    myImageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this);
    myGridView.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    ll.addView(header);
    ll.addView(myGridView);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

The snapshot:

[image]

Comment: snap will give more clear idea.

Comment: snapshot done, check first post

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" r using this in acitivity tag of manifest...

Comment: @ArpitGarg I think you are right, he may get success after hiding title bar

Comment: my tittle bar is hidden, please check my code again, i updated it with some more code to hidde the bar. The error is still here.

Comment: gr8.. I have also suggeted full screen tag Please refer to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: This should work just fine if you set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"` in the Manifest.

```
public class MainGrid extends Activity {
    private GridView myGridView;
    private ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
    private ImageView header;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ll.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);   // SET THIS TO TOP

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    ll.setLayoutParams(lp);
    // I'VE ADDED LAYOUTPARAMS TOO

    header = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    header.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_acc);

    myGridView = new GridView(this);
    myImageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this);
    myGridView.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    ll.addView(header);
    ll.addView(myGridView);
    setContentView(ll);
}
```

Comment: i can't use XML files because this app is generated with our company app generator, and it can't use XML files for the layout. They must be generated with java code.

Comment: Then you can use LayoutParams to set the params on the ImageView when adding it to the LinearLayout. add "Set ALIGN_PARENT_TOP" to your params. You might want to do it for both your LinearLayout and you ImageView.

Comment: ALIGN_PARENT_TOP is from RelativeLayout, i'm not using a relativeLayout here, then that is not the problem/solution :/

Comment: Did you manage to set the set NoTitleBar in the Manifest? You need to put it in <Application android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"> ?

Comment: yes, i tested that and more manifest things from the other answer

Comment: I posted the wrong line sorry, i meant this: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" And that didn't work? You might need to delete the two lines that does it in your code. Else you might need to convert to RelativeLayout, I've got a working example with a LinearLayout that containing a RelativeLayout with an ImageView that aligns the top completely. So you might wanna do that if you cant find a solution. You can also take a look at the ActionBar, i've not tried it myself, but it might be helpful?

Comment: im trying to do with relativelayout but i can't do it, it's the first time i work with relativelayout and java, and it is hard to do it... really isn't possible to do this with linearlayout simply?

Comment: I've updated my original post. This works in a app I just made. If you still have the space on top, it's because your picture isn't cropped, but have a transparent background/frame. This is all I can do for you mate :)

Comment: I will test it in some mins. But, the manifest line, where should be putted? on the activity or on application?  this line: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"

Comment: ok, finally i did it copying and pasting your code and it still fails. Is not for my image, i tested it with various header images without spacing on top. The problem is that android is putting a "invisible" padding between each of the elements of the linearLayout. And also between the LinearLayout and the top of the window.... Isn't possible to avoid it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4139/discussion-between-finn-larsen-and-pableras84)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using the title bar, you can always get rid of it:

http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2009/07/removing-title-bar-from-your-android.html

Comment: i'm not using it... that is not the problem, check the code, i updated it with the lines where i remove the tittle bar

Comment: no, i did this: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar". How can i make fullscreen in the manifest?

Comment: android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.FullScreen"

Comment: i tryed all your solutions but none of them works. Still continue with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Using this in for activity tag in manifest solves your problem

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

For Full screen you should use

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

Comment: ..... other guy told me that on his solution and i allready have tested it and doesn't works, the problem is still here

Comment: kk,, Also set params for LinearLayout as LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

Comment: remove ll.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); Also I am doughtfull for the image.. Try to set Background color for header view say any #223344 Is it Showing complete..