# ImageView and LinearLayout, the imageview it's getting blank spaces on top and bottom of the Image

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm having some issues with LinearLayout and ImageView on Android. I must not use XML for defining the layouts, i'm trying to understand to do it with java code.

I have two elements on the linearLayout, a header (imageview) and a body (gridview with images). Someting is going wrong because the imageview it's getting some blanck spaces on top and on bottom of the original Image.

The original Imageview that i am using for the Header doesn't have these white spaces on top and on bottom of the image, i put the line header.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); and then i noticed that something was going wrong with the imageview because its getting these blanck spaces.

**I tested with multiple header images and i noticed that the higher height haves the image, the bigger are the blanck spaces** so, they are generated dinamically for some kind of error/bug

How to remove them?

Here is a capture:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    header = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    header.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_acc_old);
    header.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    myGridView = new GridView(this);
    myImageAdapter=new ImageAdapter(this);
    myGridView.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);

    ll.addView(header);
    ll.addView(myGridView);
    setContentView(ll);
```

I Tryed with these solutions, but they didn't work:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.addView(header,layoutParams);
```

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7710915/how-to-remove-the-black-space-between-the-tittle-bar-and-the-first-element-of-a-l

Comment: Try, header.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY)

Comment: Dr.nik, isn't a duplicate, remove your comment please, they are completly different questions. This question is not for a LinearLayout issue, is for a ImageView issue

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any transparent pixel on Top or bottom of image?

Comment: absolutly sure, i tested it with multiple images too. Also, the higher height haves the image, the bigger are the blanck spaces

Comment: ok post your exact onCreate method

Comment: solved with header.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `setBackgroundResource` instead of `setImageResource` while setting image to ImageView.

Comment: i tryed it, and the Header dissapears, it is not the solution

Comment: Did you also remove header.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE); this line?

Comment: Ok, if i remove that line, then the blank spaces dissapear!!! but the image get's stretched and i dont want that the image gets streched :S how to solve that?

Comment: You take screen shot of that screen get dimension of header from that screen shot and ask your designer to create a image of that dimension.

Comment: Or try setting following to header LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);.

Comment: Great! Which method you used for setting image resource? setBackgroundResource or setImageResource.

Comment: Awesome, android:adjustViewBounds="true" worked for me (I'm just using xml not doing it programatically) and I'm still using android:src in my ImageView (which itself is inside a RelativeLayout).